# Finding the exact label with change (selected or unselected value) on dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown with all the options as selected by default. When I unselect an option, I want to disable one div. But if someone selects it back, I want to reenable it.

I have a working code, but it is very naive. Currently, whenever there is a change event on dropdown, I get all the unselected options and selected options. And accordingly apply or remove the css.

```
<select class="ss-select" data-dropup-auto="false" id="ss_options" multiple="multiple" name="ss">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">One</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">Two</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="3">Three</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="4">Four</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="5">Five</option>
</select>
```

This is jQuery code:

```
$("#ss_options").change(function(){
    $('#ss_options').find('option').not(':selected').each(function(k,v){
        console.log(k,v.text, v.value);
        $("label:contains('"+v.text+"')").closest("div").children().css({"pointer-events": "none", "opacity": "0.4"});
    });
    $('#ss_options option:selected').each(function(k,v){
        console.log(k,v.text, v.value);
        $("label:contains('"+v.text+"')").closest("div").children().css({"pointer-events": "", "opacity": ""});
    });
});
```

The above code is working find, but it iterates over all entire list of dropdown options again and it applies/ removes css. Is there a way to optimize it?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to optimize it?

You can define a class like:

```
<style>
    .newclass {
        pointer-events: none;
        opacity: 0.4
    }
</style>
```

Now, on change event you can toggle that class on elements:

```js
$("#ss_options").on('change', function (e) {
    $("div.radio-block > *").addClass('newclass');
    $(this).find('option:selected').each(function(idx, ele) {
        $("div.radio-block:has(label:contains('" + ele.text + "')) > *").removeClass('newclass');
    });
});
```

```css
.newclass {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.4
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select class="ss-select" data-dropup-auto="false" id="ss_options" multiple="multiple" name="ss">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">One</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="2">Two</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="3">Three</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="4">Four</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="5">Five</option>
</select>

<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="radio-block">
        <input type="checkbox" id="ss_options_checkbox1" class="ss-options-checkbox ss-hidden-checkbox-input">
        <label for="ss_options_checkbox1" class="ss-checkbox-legend">One</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="radio-block">
        <input type="checkbox" id="ss_options_checkbox2" class="ss-options-checkbox ss-hidden-checkbox-input">
        <label for="ss_options_checkbox2" class="ss-checkbox-legend">Two</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="radio-block">
        <input type="checkbox" id="ss_options_checkbox3" class="ss-options-checkbox ss-hidden-checkbox-input">
        <label for="ss_options_checkbox3" class="ss-checkbox-legend">Three</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="radio-block">
        <input type="checkbox" id="ss_options_checkbox4" class="ss-options-checkbox ss-hidden-checkbox-input">
        <label for="ss_options_checkbox4" class="ss-checkbox-legend">Four</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <div class="radio-block">
        <input type="checkbox" id="ss_options_checkbox5" class="ss-options-checkbox ss-hidden-checkbox-input">
        <label for="ss_options_checkbox5" class="ss-checkbox-legend">Five</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `this.selectedIndex` is always giving me value 1, regardless of the option I select